# Getting compile time error : The import net.corda.core.testing cannot be resolved

Tags: java, corda

I am using gradle + Eclipse(Oxygen), and I'm trying to implement Unit testing for my Corda app, for this I am following the example from https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-test-dsl.html

Here they have used:

```
import static net.corda.core.testing.JavaTestHelpers.*;
import static net.corda.core.contracts.JavaTestHelpers.*;

@Test
public void emptyLedger() {
    ledger(l -> {
        return Unit.INSTANCE; // We need to return this explicitly
    });
}
```

Here I'm getting compile time error as following:

```
The import net.corda.core.testing cannot be resolved. 
There is no package called net.corda.core.testing, and no javadocs.
```

Comment: Do you have this jar in your classpath?

Comment: @Mureinik, issue is resolved, I know that testing libraries are in `net.corda.testing`, but when I see the documentation I thought that it is moved as part of v2

Answer (score 2):

The Corda testing libraries are in the package `net.corda.testing`, and not `net.corda.core.testing`.